# Chunk counld not split when the chunksize greater than specified chunksize

Tags: mongodb, split

Here is the situation:

There is a chunk, has the shard key range `[10001, 100030]`, but currently, it has only one key `(e.g. 10001)` has the data, key range from `[10002, 10030]` is just empty, the chuck data is beyond `8M`, then we set the current chuck size to `8M`.

After we fill the data in the key range `[10002, 10030]`, this chunk starts to split, and stopped at a key range like this `[10001, 10003], it has two keys, and we just wonder if this is OK or not.

From the document on the official site we thought that the chunk might NOT contains more than ONE key.

So, would you please help us make sure if this is ok or not ?

What we want to is to split the chunks as many as possible, so that to make sure the data is balanced.

Comment: There is a [Migration Threshold](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-balancing/#migration-thresholds) which needs to be crossed in order to trigger chunks to be actually migrated. Please note that chunk migrations are actually a rather expensive operation. You should rather choose your shard key wisely in order to make sure data is written evenly to the shards.

Comment: Thanks, I kwow that . But the problem is when the real chunksize greate than specified chunksize , this chunk counldn't split and the chunk contain two or more shard key,and each data size of each shard key greater than specified chunksize , I don't know why the chunk counldn't split.

Answer (score 0):

There is a notion called [jumbo chunks](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-chunk-migration/#jumbo-chunks). Every chunk which exceeds its specified size or has more documents than the maximum configured is considered a jumbo chunk.

Since MongoDB usually splits a chunk when about half the chunk size is reached, I take Jumbo chunks as a sign that there is something rather wrong with the cluster.

The most likely reason for jumbo chunks is that one or more config servers wasn't available for a time.

Metadata updates need to be written to all three config servers (they don't build a replica set), metadata updates can not be made in case one of the config servers is down. Both chunk splitting and migration need a metadata update. So when one config server is down, a chunk can not be split early enough and it will grow in size and ultimately become a jumbo chunk.

Jumbo chunks aren't automatically split, even when all three config servers are available. The reason for this is... Well, IMHO MongoDB plays a little save here. And Jumbo chunks aren't moved, either. The reason for this is rather obvious - moving data which in theory can have any size > 16MB simply is a too costly operation.

**Proceed at your own risk! You have been warned!**

Since you can identify the jumbo chunks, they are pretty easy to deal with.
Simply identify the key range of the chunk and use it within

```
sh.splitFind("database.collection", query)
```

This will identify the shard in question and split in half, which is quite important. Please, please read [*Split Chunks in a Sharded Cluste*r](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/split-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/) and make sure you understood all of it and the implications before trying to split the chunks manually.